# How to make a fixed div x scrollable

Tags: css

how can I create a x scrollable div?
The div should be placed to a fixed position?

With this code it does not scroll. I think it is because of fixed position.

```css
.picdiv {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="picdiv">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Bild_der_Wissenschaft_Logo.svg/400px-Bild_der_Wissenschaft_Logo.svg.png">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Bild_der_Wissenschaft_Logo.svg/400px-Bild_der_Wissenschaft_Logo.svg.png">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Bild_der_Wissenschaft_Logo.svg/400px-Bild_der_Wissenschaft_Logo.svg.png">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
      Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
      Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla
      mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Your asking for a juxtaposition. You want something to scroll _and_ be fixed.  I think you want it to be fixed in context A and scrollable in context B.  If that is the case, please provide the definintions for context A & B.

Comment: your div with images is x-scrollable for me

Comment: Sorry, but for me not.
@ Pineda if it is possible to fix my problem, I can create a div around it, and I can put it to a fixed position too. Into this case, the div inside should have a height of 60px and a width of 80% of my screen width.

I created ist here: https://jsfiddle.net/mondy/mdm5queq/

Comment: @Mondy your fiddle is not scrollable, though code snippet you've provided is working fine here, can you confirm it works for you here?

Comment: It works for me here too.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment but your overflow-x is not working because images are going one under another and their width is under 80% of your .picdiv class which won't use scroll x if images are in line it will work..